# Ubuntu 14.04: what is the difference between python in /usr/local/bin/python and /usr/bin/python?

Tags: python, uninstallation

Am I installing python repeatedly? How do I remove python in /usr/local/bin/python and install python only in /usr/bin/python?
I tried make uninstall from the source file but it says there's no uninstall target. What do I do?

Comment: What does `/usr/local/bin/python -V` tell you about that version, versus `/usr/bin/python -V`? What OS is this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the OS. I'm using ubuntu 14.04. /usr/local/bin/python -V 2.7.10. /usr/bin/python -V 2.7.6

Comment: Then someone (you?) installed Python 2.7.10 (latest release in the 2.7 branch) into /usr/local. That's quite normal if you need to get the latest bugfix release vs. the one that Ubuntu bundles. The one in `/usr/bin` is the official Ubuntu packaged version, just leave it be.

Comment: You installed it in /usr/local/bin.  Do **not** touch the python in /usr/bin, if you do you will be reinstalling ubuntu. What does `which python` output?

Comment: Yes, it was me who installed python in the local directory. So is it OK to have two versions of python? Can both python versions use the packages I installed? Do I need to update the ubuntu bundled python?

Comment: @grayred, the system python is in /usr/bin, ubuntu relies heavily on it so don't screw with it unless you know exactly what you are doing.  You can have a million version of python if you want but it can become a pain very fast. I use pyenv to install different versions which you can activate/deactivate  easily. https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Comment: Thank you, Padraic and Martijn. I'm trying pyenv.

Comment: By the way, how do I remove python installed in the local directory if I don't want it anymore?